# How to account for Covariances in a Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: r, regression, simulation, monte-carlo, marginal-effect

I am conducting a regression analysis of Z on X and Y. I am interesting in interpreting the marginal effect. The model includes quadratic terms for both X and Y as well as an interaction term X*Y. If I look at just the marginal effect of X on Z (the partial derivative of Z wrt X) I get the equation:

```
ME <- function(x, y){0.187 - 0.000472*x - 0.000252*y}
```

I am interested in the point at which this ME becomes zero and hence the partial effect becomes negative. I am calling this a "tipping point".
So to calculate the tipping point, let the ME equation follow the form: 0 = a + b*x +c*y. Solving this for x gives the tipping point im interested in. Rather than taking this at face value, I would like to construct a distribution using a Monte Carlo simulation. I created the following r code:

```
set.seed(123)
a = rnorm(1000, mean=0.187, sd=0.016711349)
b = rnorm(1000, mean=-0.000472, sd=0.000046643)
c = rnorm(1000, mean=-0.000252, sd=0.00010862)
y = rnorm(1000, mean=16.53, sd=7.569)

x = (a+c*y)/-b
```

Where the means of a, b, and c are the parameter estimates from the regression and the SDs are their associated standard errors. The mean and SD of y are from summary statistics of the data.

What I am unsure of, is how to account for any covariance between any of a, b, and c? Or if there would be any issue to begin with?

P.S. I doubt the title of my question accurately reflects my question so it would be helpful if somebody could better characterize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two viable options in your case (there is probably many more).

Option 1:

Since you have data, you could use bootstrap to resample `a,b,c,x,y` instead of assuming that they are independent with their respectives means and standard deviations. This will preserve the properties of your data (covariances as you want, but distributions also).

Option 2:

If you can not use bootstrap, you can also use the variance matrix of the estimator, which is $\text{var} (\hat{\beta})=\sigma^2 (X^\prime X)^{-1}$, where is $X$ is your predictors and $\sigma^2$ is the variance of residual error in your outcome. The diagonal elements are the same as you use as `sd`, but will include covariances also. You can then use this matrix to generate data as you have carried out. Using package MASS in R should easily do the job.

Comment: lovely answer, appreciate it. I kind of understand where bootstrapping comes into play now, also thanks for the package recommendation.